# Transfer of data between Python files

Tags: python-3.x

Need some help please to explain why the following does not work. 
Environment: Python 3.4, Gtk3.0, limited experience of Python
File selectcontact.py contains code to select one of a number of records and pass its key back to its parent process for use in one of at least three other actions.

Code snippet from the parent class:

```
….
        self.cindex = 0
….
    def editcontact_clicked (self, menuitem):
        import selectcontact
        selectcontact.SelectContactGUI(self)
        print ('From Manage ', self.cindex)
        if self.cindex > 0:
            import editcontact
            editcontact.EditContactGUI(self.db, self.cindex)
```

….

Code snippet from selectcontact:
class SelectContactGUI:
    def **init**(self, parent_class):

```
    self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
    self.builder.add_from_file(UI_FILE)
    self.builder.connect_signals(self)

    self.parent_class = parent_class
    self.db = parent_class.db
    self.cursor = self.db.cursor(cursor_factory = psycopg2.extras.NamedTupleCursor)

    self.contact_store = self.builder.get_object('contact_store')

    self.window = self.builder.get_object('window1')
    self.window.show_all()

def select_contact_path(self, path):
    self.builder.get_object('treeview_selection1').select_path(path)

def contact_treerow_changed (self, treeview):
    selection = self.builder.get_object('treeview_selection1')
    model, path = selection.get_selected()
    if path != None:
        self.parent_class.cindex = model[path][0]
        print ('From select ', self.parent_class.cindex)
    self.window.destroy()
```

….

window1 is declared as “modal”, so I was expecting the call to selectcontact to act as a subroutine, so that editcontact wouldn’t be called until control was passed back to the parent. The parent_class bit works because the contact_store is correctly populated. However the transfer back to the parent appears not to work, and the two print statements occur in the wrong order:
From Manage  0
From select  2
Comments gratefully received.
Graeme

Answer (score 0):

"Modal" refers to windows only.  That is, a modal window prevents accessing the parent window.

It has little to do with what code is running.  I am not familiar with this particular windowing framework, but any I have worked with has had a separate thread for GUI and at least one for processing, to keep the GUI responsive, and message loops running in all active windows, not just the one currently with the focus.  The modal dialog has no control over what code in other threads are executed when.

You should be able to break into the debugger and see what threads are running and what is running in each thread at any given time.